# How to load all variables from a .mat file(saved as -v7.3) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, h5py, mat-file

I have a .mat file saved as -v7.3 in matlab and contains 1000 variables named x1 to x1000. My objective is to transfer(or load) all these variables into something like X_train which will be used as an input data for an encoder-decoder based neural network. I can access a single variable using the following code:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('input.mat', 'r') as f:
    x1 = list(f['x1'])
```

But I want to access all 1000 variables and store them somewhere to feed them in my network (Any other way beside storing them and feeding them into network is also appreciated). **All variables are of size 12x24x12.**
I also thought of looping through all the variables and store them in a pandas dataframe(I don't know exactly how that works) by using below code in addition to above code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(x1))
```

but I got an error 'ValueError: Must pass 2-d input' and dropped the looping through idea.

I looked online but could only find the answer to get the list of variables but not the variables themselves and got no solution to my problem. So in short i need a way to store or feed all 1000 3-d variables as input for an encoder-decoder based neural network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alist = [f[k][:] for k in f.keys()]
```

should load all arrays into a list.

```
np.stack(alist)
```

should create a 4d array